# i have latest nodejs version installed,but i can't update npm as well (windows)

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, cmd, updates

i updated my nodejs to the latest stable version v15.7.0.my npm version is now 5.5.1 I tried commands `C:\Users\Asus>npm update -g` and `C:\Users\Asus>npm install -g npm@latest`
to updating **npm**.but i got this errors each time:

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v15.7.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-28T11_03_53_376Z-debug.log
```

any idea how can i fix it?

Comment: try sudo maybe? `sudo npm install -g npm@latest`

Comment: i'm in windows,it doesn't work with sudo

Comment: You can try to downgrade your node.js instalation to one version that npm has support.

Comment: by downgarding shows same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the solution :
https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2874#issuecomment-663661148

i deleted npm and npm cache folders in Appdata>Roaming and then reinstalled nodejs

Answer (score 1):

As per https://nodejs.org/en/download/ (as per today), it is mentioned as `Latest LTS Version: 14.15.4 (includes npm 6.14.10)`

Since node installation includes NPM also, you don't need to install it separately.

so cleanest way is to uninstall node from your machine and install it freshly which automatically gets you compatible NPM

Comment: i unistalled and reinstalled it ,when i use `npm -v` it shows 5.5.1 again as version

Comment: now i tried `C:\Users\Asus>npm i -g npm@6.14.10` it shows previous errros plus `WARNING: You are likely using a version of node-tar or npm that is incompatible with this version of Node.js.
Please use either the version of npm that is bundled with Node.js, or a version of npm (> 5.5.1 or < 5.4.0) or node-tar (> 4.0.1) that is compatible with Node.js 9 and above.
npm[4324]: c:\ws\src\node_zlib.cc:576: Assertion `args.Length() == 7 && "init(windowBits, level, memLevel, strategy, writeResult, writeCallback," " dictionary)"' failed.`

Answer (score 0):

Open PowerShell as Administrator and execute following commands,

```
> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
> npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
> npm-windows-upgrade
```